# #XAML throw exception in OxyPlot

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, oxyplot

When I compile my program, it have no errors, but when I've trying to running, VS2015 throw exeption in XAML:

> Could not load file or assembly 'OxyPlot.Wpf, Version = 2011.3.4094.38387, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 75e952ba404cdbb0' or one of its dependencies. Located definition of the manifesto set does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

(I'm using google translator, becouse I've Polish lang OS, so VS throw exeption in that language)

I'm not sure where is problem,
here is xaml code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
    <oxy:PlotView Height="50" Margin="2" Model="{Binding AmplitudeSquareModel}"/>           
</StackPanel>
```

and *.cs file:

```
public PlotModel AmplitudeSquareModel { get; private set; }

private double AmplitudeSquare(double _amp, int time)
{
    double res = 0;
    double time_d = time;
    for (int j = 1; j < 100; ++j)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 1)
            res += (Math.Sin(j * (time_d / 10)) / j);
    }
    res *= (4 * _amp) / Math.PI;
    return res;
}

public void Draw(int HowManyIteration)
{
    List<double> square = new List<double>();

    this.AmplitudeSquareModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Square" };

    for (int i = 0; i < HowManyIteration; ++i)
    {
        Func<double, double> SquareFun = (x) => AmplitudeSquare(4, i);
        AmplitudeSquareModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(SquareFun, 0, 100, 0.1, "square"));
    }
}
```

Really I don't know where problem is...

Comment: Did you installed Oxyplot via nuget?

Comment: Yes, i've installed via nugget

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/750) you are using an unstable version. Have you tried another version?

Comment: I'm using latest unstable version, and some kinda other, but it's the same result - moreover I create new project and copy everything from documentation and it works, so I don't know, meabe I copy everything from not working project to working project.

Comment: The exception you are getting does not depend on your code. Some component is either missing or buggy